# Can a user with a role that denies SELECT on a particular attribute value infer items in the Table (with that value)?

Tags: sql, database, rdbms

Consider a table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE Farm (
    ID INT,
    Name CHAR(1),
    Contents VARCHAR(255),
    Level VARCHAR(50)
);
```

```
INSERT INTO Farm (ID, Name, Contents, Level)
VALUES 
(1, 'A', 'Cats', 'Low'),
(1, 'B', 'Dogs', 'Low'),
(1, 'C', 'Lions', 'High'),
(1, 'D', 'Pups', 'Low');
```

Role A has all the access rights to the table, while Role B has all the rights with rows where the Level is 'Low'. Is there a possible case where a user-assigned Role B could infer that there is a name with Level as "High" in the table?

Note: The user can cross-reference the ID key with other tables

From my research I found that Role B would be given access to all privileges on a view that has just the "Low" level information and Role A would have all four rows and even if the user with Role B were to run COUNT(*) they wouldn't know if an entry with Level as "High" even exists

Comment: Add a tag for the dbms you're using, to get accurate attention and answers.

Comment: Also show us the view definition.

Comment: view definition:

CREATE VIEW farm_role2 AS
SELECT * 
FROM Farm 
WHERE Level = 'Low';

Comment: With dbms tag I meant for the specific product you're using. Oracle suggested by the answer you've already got. But there are many others as well.

Comment: I am using mySQL, but open to suggestions from all kinds of products

Comment: Select from the base table will return all fours rows, for anyone with select privilege. Select from the view will return the three Low rows, for anyone with select privilege.

Comment: if there is a uniqueness constraint one to many relationship on ID and Name, then if a user with less privileges tries to insert to C their query would fail because of the constraint?

Comment: Constraints are defined, and verified, for the base table.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If user granted select privileges to ***oracle system tables*** such as ***DBA_COL_PRIVS***.

```
SELECT * FROM DBA_COL_PRIVS;
```

Comment: consider, no privileges will be granted to the user. how about then?

Comment: @0xfffe Then no. Maybe document? I wonder why you want to block all information to user. if Role 1 user quit, it might be hard to know the tables info and history.

Comment: If the user with limited privileges tries to insert into the table, would that work? how about in a case where there is a uniqueness constraint on the "Name" column?